# Let Σ={a,b,c}. How many languages over Σ are there such that each string in the language has length 2 or less?

Tags: finite-automata

First of all I see the number of strings as the following:

1 (epsilon 0 length string) + 3 (pick one letter) + 9 (3 options for first letter, 3 options for second)

For a total of 13 strings. Now as far as I know a language can pick any combination of this for example l1 = {ab,a,ac} l2 = {c}

I'm not sure how to calculate the total number of languages there could be here. Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a set with 13 elements. A particular language could be any subset of this set. How many subsets does this set have?

This is called the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of that set, and it has 2<sup>13</sup> elements.

Answer (score 0):

Cardinality of character set, say d = 3.

Total words possible of length (<= k), say w = (d^(k+1) - 1)/(d-1) = 13.

Total languages possible = [Power Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) {Each word can be included or not} =  2^w = 8192.